# Any good guides on using PTRACE_SYSEMU?

Tags: linux, ptrace

Does anyone have any good explanations, tutorials, books, or guides on the use of [PTRACE_SYSEMU](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/ptrace.2.html)?

Comment: This is very specific x86 user-mode linux optimization, check http://sysemu.sourceforge.net/ site from its author. Basically you should not use SYSEMU of ptrace.

Answer (score 1):

What I found interesting:

- [Example Implementation for ptrace](https://web.archive.org/web/20090425073122/http://www.comp.glam.ac.uk/pages/staff/hggross/IntelligentTimingAnalysis_HTML/node20.html)
- [Playing with ptrace, Part I  - LinuxJournal.com](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6100)
- [Playing with ptrace, Part II - LinuxJournal.com](http://www.linuxjournal.com/node/6210)

And programming library that makes using ptrace easier :

- [PinkTrace - ptrace() wrapper library.](http://dev.exherbo.org/~alip/pinktrace/)

For pinktrace there are examples, sydbox sources are example of complex pinktrace usecase. In general, I've found author as good person to contact about using and testing pinktrace.

Comment: I know how to use ptrace in general, just not the PTRACE_SYSEMU option. I was looking for a guide specifically on that, which none of these articles cover. I know user-mode Linux used it at one point, but I was hoping for something a little more high-level instead of wading through code.

Comment: I think a good person to ask about usage of PTRACE_SYSEMU might be [pinktrace author](http://dev.exherbo.org/~alip/pinktrace/) - just try ;).

Comment: @GrzegorzWierzowiecki: Even I wanted some guides which explains some of the advanced options. If you find any can you update it here ?? :)
thanks in advance :)

Comment: Hey its 2016 I don't know if you found any resources but the man pages still state PTRACE_SINGLESTEP, PTRACE_SYSEMU, PTRACE_SYSEMU_SINGLESTEP Details of these kinds of stops are yet to be documented. So did you find a resource?

Answer (score 0):

There is small test from linux kernel sources which uses PTRACE_SYSEMU:

http://code.metager.de/source/xref/linux/stable/tools/testing/selftests/x86/ptrace_syscall.c
or http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/tools/testing/selftests/x86/ptrace_syscall.c

```
186 struct user_regs_struct regs;
187
188 printf("[RUN]\tSYSEMU\n");
189 if (ptrace(PTRACE_SYSEMU, chld, 0, 0) != 0)
190     err(1, "PTRACE_SYSCALL");
191 wait_trap(chld);
192
193 if (ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, chld, 0, &regs) != 0)
194     err(1, "PTRACE_GETREGS");
195
196 if (regs.user_syscall_nr != SYS_gettid ||
197     regs.user_arg0 != 10 || regs.user_arg1 != 11 ||
198     regs.user_arg2 != 12 || regs.user_arg3 != 13 ||
199     regs.user_arg4 != 14 || regs.user_arg5 != 15) {
200     printf("[FAIL]\tInitial args are wrong (nr=%lu, args=%lu %lu %lu %lu %lu %lu)\n", (unsigned long)regs.user_syscall_nr, (unsigned long)regs.user_arg0, (unsigned long)regs.user_arg1, (unsigned long)regs.user_arg2, (unsigned long)regs.user_arg3, (unsigned long)regs.user_arg4, (unsigned long)regs.user_arg5);
201     nerrs++;
202 } else {
203     printf("[OK]\tInitial nr and args are correct\n");
204 }
205
206 printf("[RUN]\tRestart the syscall (ip = 0x%lx)\n",
207        (unsigned long)regs.user_ip);
208
209 /*
210  * This does exactly what it appears to do if syscall is int80 or
211  * SYSCALL64.  For SYSCALL32 or SYSENTER, though, this is highly
212  * magical.  It needs to work so that ptrace and syscall restart
213  * work as expected.
214  */
215 regs.user_ax = regs.user_syscall_nr;
216 regs.user_ip -= 2;
217 if (ptrace(PTRACE_SETREGS, chld, 0, &regs) != 0)
218     err(1, "PTRACE_SETREGS");
219
220 if (ptrace(PTRACE_SYSEMU, chld, 0, 0) != 0)
221     err(1, "PTRACE_SYSCALL");
222 wait_trap(chld);
223
224 if (ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, chld, 0, &regs) != 0)
225     err(1, "PTRACE_GETREGS");
226
```

So, it looks like just another `ptrace` call which will allow program to run until next system call is made by it; then stop child and signal the ptracer. It can read registers, optionally change some and restart the syscall.

Implemented in http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/ptrace.c?v=4.10#L1039 like other stepping `ptrace` calls:

```
1039 #ifdef PTRACE_SINGLESTEP
1040         case PTRACE_SINGLESTEP:
1041 #endif
1042 #ifdef PTRACE_SINGLEBLOCK
1043         case PTRACE_SINGLEBLOCK:
1044 #endif
1045 #ifdef PTRACE_SYSEMU
1046         case PTRACE_SYSEMU:
1047         case PTRACE_SYSEMU_SINGLESTEP:
1048 #endif
1049         case PTRACE_SYSCALL:
1050         case PTRACE_CONT:
1051                 return ptrace_resume(child, request, data);
```

And man page has some info: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html

> PTRACE_SYSEMU, PTRACE_SYSEMU_SINGLESTEP (since Linux 2.6.14)
>                 For PTRACE_SYSEMU, continue and stop on entry to the next
>                 system call, which will not be executed.  See the
>                 documentation on syscall-stops below.  For
>                 PTRACE_SYSEMU_SINGLESTEP, do the same but also singlestep if
>                 not a system call.  This call is **used by programs like User
>                 Mode Linux** that want to emulate all the tracee's system calls.
>                 The data argument is treated as for PTRACE_CONT.  The addr
>                 argument is ignored.  These requests are currently supported
>                 only on x86.

So, it is not portable and used only for Usermode linux (um) on x86 platform as variant of classic `PTRACE_SYSCALL`. And um test for sysemu with some comments is here: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/um/os-Linux/start_up.c?v=4.10#L155

```
155 __uml_setup("nosysemu", nosysemu_cmd_param,
156 "nosysemu\n"
157 "    Turns off syscall emulation patch for ptrace (SYSEMU) on.\n"
158 "    SYSEMU is a performance-patch introduced by Laurent Vivier. It changes\n"
159 "    behaviour of ptrace() and helps reducing host context switch rate.\n"
160 "    To make it working, you need a kernel patch for your host, too.\n"
161 "    See http://perso.wanadoo.fr/laurent.vivier/UML/ for further \n"
162 "    information.\n\n");
163 
164 static void __init check_sysemu(void)
```

Link in comment was redirecting to secret site http://sysemu.sourceforge.net/ from 2004:

> Why ?
>
> UML uses ptrace() and PTRACE_SYSCALL to catch system calls. But, by
>   this way, you can't remove the real system call, only monitor it. UML,
>   to avoid the real syscall and emulate it, replaces the real syscall by
>   a call to getpid(). This method generates two context-switches instead
>   of one. A Solution
>
> A solution is to change the behaviour of ptrace() to not call the real
>   syscall and thus we don't have to replace it by a call to getpid().
>   How ?
>
> By adding a new command to ptrace(), PTRACE_SYSEMU, that acts like
>   PTRACE_SYSCALL without executing syscall. To add this command we need
>   to patch the host kernel. To use this new command in UML kernel, we
>   need to patch the UML kernel too.

Comment: Also check ujail app which uses SYSEMU syscall: http://techandsp.blogspot.com/2009/12/introducing-ujail-proof-of-concept.html "Introducing ujail & proof of concept", 2009 https://code.launchpad.net/~speijnik/ujail/proof-of-concept