# How to use ptrace(2) to change behaviour of syscalls?

Tags: linux, hook, system-calls, code-injection, ptrace

Are there any guides or examples (especially ARM ones) or libraries of using `ptrace` to affect execution of other process? For example, to make it believe that some data is appeared on file descriptor (i.e. release select/poll with some result and "answer" the following read syscall before the kernel). Expecting something involving `PTRACE_SYSEMU`.

Can it be done in portable way? I want something like libc-overriding `LD_PRELOAD` trick, but which can be attached at runtime.

Can it be done with some gdb commands?

Ideal variant would be if there is some library where I can easily and portably hook into syscalls and edit them before of after the actual call is made (or emulate them), like [when doing it using LD_PRELOAD](http://www.bottomupcs.com/libraries_and_the_linker.html#AEN4508).

@link [Any good guides on using PTRACE_SYSEMU?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5395769/any-good-guides-on-using-ptrace-sysemu)

Comment: you want to look at this file to see how ptrace affect execution of other process :  - http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/tools/testing/selftests/breakpoints/breakpoint_test.c

Answer (score 1):

You can use the PTRACE_SYSCALL request: it restarts the child process (just like PTRACE_CONT) but arranges for it to stop at the next entry to or exit from a system call. For example (assume a kernel built for x86):

```c
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <linux/user.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int status = 0, pid, r;
    struct user_regs_struct uregs;

    if ((pid = fork()) == 0) {
        printf("pid = %d, ppid = %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
        ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0, 0, 0);
        kill(getpid(), SIGINT);
        r = getpid();
        printf("%d\n", r);
    } else {
        wait(&status);
        ptrace(PTRACE_SYSCALL, pid, 0, 0);
        wait(&status);
        ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, pid, 0, &uregs);

        /* this prints the syscall number of getpid */
        printf("syscall nr: %d\n", uregs.orig_eax);
        /* 64 is syscall number of getppid */
        uregs.orig_eax = 64;
        ptrace(PTRACE_SETREGS, pid, 0, &uregs);
        ptrace(PTRACE_CONT, pid, 0, 0);
        wait(&status);
        if(WIFEXITED(status))
            printf("we're done\n");
    }
}
```

The child prints its PID and delivers a signal to itself. Because of the prior call to `ptrace()` this means it will be stopped.

The parent waits for this to happen and restarts the child with PTRACE_SYSCALL, then waits. Next, the child invokes the `getpid` system call and it is stopped once again. The parent process uses the PTRACE_GETREGS invocation to peek into the child's registers, where `eax` holds the system call number. The parent changes this to the system call number of `getppid`, then once again allows the child to continue. Because the system call number has changed prior to the invocation of the system call, the child will now invoke `getppid` instead of `getpid`.

Using `ptrace` for this purpose may be portable, but I have not tested it. In gdb, you can also use the `catch syscall` command.

Comment: For x86 there is also injcode (and maybe some other tools). What about libraries for such things or (for example) ARM examples? Can it be done on a bit higher level than CPU register twiddling?

Comment: I'm not familiar with injcode but from its description it looks possible. Generally, if you want to mess with process internals, `ptrace` (and consequently a debugger) is probably the highest level of abstraction you can get.

Comment: Using gdb commands is higher level than ptrace, for example. Maybe there's something in middle (some "libptrace" that presents easy to use API for ptracing other processes in various ways; note: existing "libptrace" also seems to be x86-only...)?

Comment: Hopefully someone else can answer that question.

Comment: In my case the parent catches the call to `write`. I think glibc caches the result of getpid().