# How to trap system calls in a userspace library in Linux?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have a requirement to write a linux device driver in userspace.

How can I write a library which, when linked to an application, can handle system calls to a particular device.

The application should be able to use `open()`, `read()`, `write()`, `ioctl()` on a device such as `/dev/mydev0`, but these calls should terminate in a userspace library instead of a kernel module.

Please advise on if this is possible and how can I achieve this.

Comment: You can trap the C wrappers of such syscalls using the usual `LD_PRELOAD` tricks; you cannot trap directly the `int 80`/`sysenter` instructions (i.e., if someone calls "manually" the syscall, without going through the libc wrapper) as easily.

Comment: Hi, Can you please elaborate on how these LD_PRELOAD "tricks" work? That might be something I can use.

Comment: http://superuser.com/a/370054/25859

Comment: Using LD_PRELOAD to trap **library** calls is exceeding complex, especially if you're trying to capture all IO calls - and that's before you even begin to think about possible multithreaded calling programs.  You do not want to go that way unless you have to.  Because if a program directly makes **system** calls, you can't really trap those, as @MatteoItalia has already posted.

Comment: Following on the LD_PRELOAD tip, I stumbled up-on something similar http://www.linux-projects.org/modules/sections/index.php?op=viewarticle&artid=9. A video4linux camera driver framework written in userspace. It also uses LD_PRELOAD to provide some functionality. Unfortunately, the source code for this is not published. I am trying to write something very similar (driver for camera module which provide v4l2 support).

Answer (score 1):

Linux is a *monolithic kernel* which means in general, what you're asking is not possible; you can't write arbitrary drivers in user-mode.

You *could* (as your title alludes to), use [`ptrace(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html) to **trap** on system calls, and basically redirect them to functions in your library. That is not a simple, straightforward solution however.

See also:

- [How to use ptrace(2) to change behaviour of syscalls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13426561/how-to-use-ptrace2-to-change-behaviour-of-syscalls)

[FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) (Filesystem in USErspace) may be what you're looking for. It's a mechanism that allows filesystem drivers specifically to be implemented via a user-space process. This is how `sshfs`, for example, is implemented.

Resources:

- http://fuse.sourceforge.net/